# Laravel Bagisto create custom Core.php

Tags: laravel, plugins, overriding, customization

I am trying to customize bagisto, and hit a wall when trying to customize Core.php file.

What I want to do is edit some of the functions inside the Core.php file. I am now editing the file directly, but this is definitely not optimal.
How am I supposed to override some of the functions inside the Core.php?

I couldn't find any complete procedure online and am new to Laravel, so I'm completely lost.

To be precise I want to override the currency function like this:

```
public function currency($amount = 0)
{
    if (is_null($amount)) {
        $amount = 0;
    }
    return intval($amount);
    //return $this->formatPrice($this->convertPrice($amount), $this->getCurrentCurrency()->code);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it (I got helped).

The Core.php is called from Core/src/Http/helpers.php which creates the function core(). 
This function is then made public to all in package.lock under "autoload". 
 
To customize the Core file you would have to create a custom Core file and helper file (that calls the custom Core file) then change the composer.lock file and make it call your custom helper.